# Target all p elements that follow an h2 with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I target all p elements that follow a heading e.g....

```
<h2 class = 'history'>History</h2>
<p>this is paragraph 1</p>
<p>this is paragraph 2</p>
<p>this is paragraph 3</p>

<h2 class = 'present'>Present</h2>
<p>I don't want to target this paragraph</p>
<p>I don't want to target this paragraph</p>
<p>I don't want to target this paragraph</p>
```

by using .history + p I can target paragraph 1, but how to target the other paragraphs until I get to the 'Present' H2 tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there aren't any other `p` elements, you can use `~` instead of `+`:

```
.history ~ p
```

If there are any more `p` elements that come after your second `h2`, and you only want to select those between `h2.history` and `h2.present`, I don't think it's possible with current CSS selectors. The general sibling selector `~` matches *every `p` sibling that comes after your `h2`*, regardless of whether there are any other siblings among them.

That said, you can easily accomplish it using jQuery:

```
$('.history').nextUntil('.present')
```

Comment: Many thanks Bolt, ideally I don't want target subsequent paragraphs, I've updated my question to reflect this. Your jQuery suggestion will work great though. Since it's only styling it's not imperative that it has to be a CSS solution, although of course it would be preferred if possible.